# What does the planar graph K7 with genus 1 look like?

Tags: graph-theory

Every time I start drawing the graph I always get tripped up somewhere near the end and ultimately fail to draw the last couple lines. Most sources I consult confirm it is genus 1, but for the life of me I can't find a good visual of the graph. Does anyone know what it looks like?

Comment: I'm not surprised you're having trouble, it's not a very easy thing to do. The following article has a drawing of $K_7$ on the torus without crossing edges: http://jgaa.info/accepted/2011/DuncanGoodrichKobourov2011.15.1.pdf (it appears as figure 1 on page 10); I don't know whether it will be satisfying to look at or just frustrate you more.

Comment: That diagram was helpful, thank you! I traced it and I kind of see how it’s supposed to work now, as I originally thought it would be a relatively clean graph like the genus of K6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you google k7 on torus you can find some embeddings, example:

http://www.amotlpaa.org/math/k7torus.html

Comment: That diagram helps a lot, thank you! I found that one a lot, but never thought to view the flat diagram as a torus, and just thought the graph was something else entirely